# Syncfusion DocIO: When converting from word document to pdf, footer is nowhere to be found

Tags: c#, syncfusion

I am trying to simply convert a word document to a pdf and render it to the browser. When I do so, the converted PDF doesn't has the word document footer.

Here is my method:

```
private int ConvertShowPDF(WordDocument RevisionWordDocument)
    {
        RevisionWordDocument.ChartToImageConverter = new ChartToImageConverter();

        DocToPDFConverter converter = new DocToPDFConverter();

        try
        {
            PdfDocument pdfDocument = converter.ConvertToPDF(RevisionWordDocument);

            MemoryStream pdfStream = new MemoryStream();

            pdfDocument.Save(pdfStream);

            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=RevisionesAdministrativas.PDF");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-length", pdfStream.Length.ToString());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(pdfStream.ToArray());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

            pdfDocument.Close();

            RevisionWordDocument.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Edited.docx"), FormatType.Docx);

            RevisionWordDocument.Close();


            return 0;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            return 1;
        }


    }
```

What I am doing wrong?? This is some kind of bug? Help please. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem in my Word document

My Word document has a footer with a custom shape. [As noted in the documentation](https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/docio/conversion), custom shapes are not supported in the DocIO Syncfusion library yet.

The workaround for me was saving the document as PDF from Microsoft Word, and with Snipping Tool, taking a cropped screenshot of the the footer, saving it as a .jpg image and inserting this image in the Word document footer.

In order to be allowed to put the image edge to edge in the document footer, you can follow [this workaround](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_other/image-edge-to-edge-ignoring-margins/282700a8-a7c5-418b-ae15-d429b8bc4295).

That's it.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for using Syncfusion products.

On further analyzing with the given input document from forum #132027, we have found that document contains group shape in the footer.

Currently DocIO doesn’t provide support for grouped shapes preservation in Word to PDF conversion. We have already logged this as a feature request in our database. We will implement this feature in any of our upcoming releases and we don’t have any immediate plans to implement this feature. We usually have an interval of at least three months between releases. The feature implementation would also greatly depend on the factors such as product design, code compatibility and complexity. We will update you when this feature has been implemented.

As a work-around kindly modify the group shape as ungroup shape in the input Word document thereby it will be preserved properly in the PDF document. We have modified your Word document with image. Please find the modified document from below link.

Modified document link:
http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/forum/132027/doc/RevisionesAdministrativas-Multiples_Modified-139642195.docx

Please let us know if you have any other questions.

Regards,
Ramanan H